# How to deploy war file in root(/) context to Wildfly ver 8.1.0.Final and remove welcome-content

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm trying to put my application on the root context to wildfly.

I put this files jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
  <context-root>/</context-root>
 </jboss-web>
```

and the empty file bean.xml at WEB-INF/

The welcome-content is still working at localhost:8080
If you put localhost:8080/index.xhtml my application appears.
I tried renaming the direcctory welcome-content but no works.

SOLVED: REFRESH CACHE OF THE BROWSER